# Bad UIScrollView autorotation behavior

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have this view controller with the following hierarchy:
[image: View hierarchy]

I am just trying to load a photo and be able to scroll it and zoom it & autorotate it. Everything works well except I am getting some bad autorotation behavior. I've set the parent UINavigationController to allow rotation (by subclassing and overridng 'shouldautororate..') and I am now getting my window rotated but the scroll/imageview combination will just not fill the screen as need (on landscape it'll be cut at 320p width). The struts and springs are set right. trying fiddling with scroll/imageview.autoresizesSubviews = YES - but it won't help.

additionally  I have to do some 'ugly' things as:

```
CGPoint cntr;// = {self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2};

    if ([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        cntr.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width/2);
        cntr.y = (self.view.bounds.size.height/2);
    }
    else
    {
        cntr.y = (self.view.bounds.size.width/2);
        cntr.x = (self.view.bounds.size.height/2);
    }

    [spinner setCenter:cntr];
    [self.imageView addSubview:spinner];
```

because the self.view.bounds will not update to represent the new landscape orientation size (always returns the portait dimensions). There must be something more elegant.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need to do this, what you can do is to use autoresizing mask property. You can set the combination of following property as per your need- UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight, UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin , UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin, UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin , UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin

Answer (score 3):

Check your autoresizing flags using `NSLog`, like this:

```
NSLog(@"scroll view = %@", self.scrollView); // or whatever the scroll view is named
NSLog(@"scroll view superview autoresizesSubviews = %d", self.scrollView.superview.autoresizesSubviews);
```

You want to see something like this:

```
scroll view = <UIScrollView: 0xdbdf200; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xd35efb0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
scroll view superview autoresizesSubviews = 1
```

The autoresize will be "W+H" if the flags are set correctly, and the superview should have the `autoresizesSubviews` property set to `YES` (logged as `1`).

If autoresizing isn't working, I highly recommend figuring out why not, because putting in a hack to manually resize on rotation will just make your code harder to maintain.

That said, the system sends your view controller several messages related to interface rotation.  Some are sent before the root view's bounds are updated, and some are sent after.  The order is this:

1. The system sends you `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.
2. The system sends you `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`.
3. The system changes the root view's bounds and transform to reflect the new interface orientation.  Thanks to autoresizing and overrides of `layoutSubviews`, this normally takes care of laying out the whole view hierarchy.
4. The system sends you `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`.
5. The system performs the animations.
6. The system sends you `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.

So if you need to adjust your UI layout for an interface rotation, you can either do it by overriding `layoutSubviews` on your custom view subclasses, or you can do it in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, which is sent **after** the root view's bounds have been updated.

Comment: OK, I am getting this:

`
scroll view = <UIScrollView: 0x79b39a0; frame = (-20 -21; 360 407); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x79a7740>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
scroll view superview autoresizesSubviews = 1
`

so no autoresize = W+H for me... Things is the [self] is a Viewcontroller which contains a view->scrollview->imageview. The image/scrollview are IBOutlets in the viewcontroller and are default classes. Are you saying I should subclass them both? or add a category in the h file for modifying their `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`... I'm lost.

Comment: You should not add a category.  You should set the autoresizingMask on the scroll view.  Perhaps you didn't have the correct view selected in the nib when you thought you set the flags.  You could try setting them in `viewDidLoad`.